# Sunspot facet option for an array-type attribute

Tags: sunspot, facet, sunspot-rails

I have researched on this question but found nothing close. Thats why I decide to ask. Stackoverflow has been a tremendous help for me.

I have a `jobs` table with one attribute is location. Each `job.location` is either in New York, Boston, or both (New York & Boston).

In sunspot solr for rails, how do I create facet for this attribute so that if a `job.location` is in both cities, the job can be displayed in the results when either New York or Boston is selected in the facet?

Should it be like an array `['New York', 'Boston']`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your design so that you have a separate Location class and set the Job class to have `has_and_belongs_to_many :locations` because it is a many-to-many relationship.
Then you can create an integer scope in your Job class searchable block for the location:

```
integer :locations, :multiple => true
```

to allow multiple locations per job.

Now it is easy to add a `facet(:locations)` that will do exactly what you want.

The above works for any number of locations, not only two. However, if you don't want to create a new class/table and are sure you only have 1 or 2 locations, you can just create a query scope field:

```
integer :locations, :multiple => true do
  if location == 'NY & Boston'
    ['NY', 'Boston']
  else
    [location]
  end
end
```